# Probability Estimation with Chernoff Bound

Tags: probability-theory, chernoff-bounds

Let's say there is an unfair coin with $P[head]=p$. We do not now $p$ but we know that $p \geq a$ for a known $a$. After $n$ trials we get $bn$ heads. Now, we want to estimate $p$ so that

- $P[|p-b|\geq gp] \leq \epsilon$, where $g, \epsilon$ are known

Here is what I have got so far:

- We know that $\mu = np$
- **not sure if the following steps are valid**
- I multiply both terms of the inequality with $n$: $P[n|p-b|\geq npg]$
- Due to the fact that $n >0, np = \mu$ and the symmetry of absolute difference I get to: $P[|nb-\mu| \geq g\mu] \leq \epsilon$, which resembles the two-sided **Chernoff-Inequality**
- Thus, I make the following equality: $\epsilon = 2e^{-\mu g^2/3}$
- From there, I solve for $p$.

The problem is that this way, $p$ could be negative which does not make any sense.

Any input would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: What about the estimate $p = \max(a,b)$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus how do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: This would be my guess given the available data.

Comment: Okay, but I am interested in the thought process that made you make this estimation

Comment: The sample mean is $b$, so the obvious guess for the bias is $b$. We are also given that the bias is at least $a$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get your reasoning. Is there any way to make such an estimation by using Chernoff's inequality? (as I tried)

Comment: Chernoff's inequality answers a different question, namely it bounds the probability that $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ is far away from its mean $pn$.